# Ruby saml Service Provider entity id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, saml, application-settings

I am setting up SAML auth on my project. 
I use [ruby-saml](https://github.com/onelogin/ruby-saml) gem for this.

Now, connecting to Identity Provider, I was asked to provide them entity id. 
I can't seem to find such setting in ruby-saml. It has Identity Provider's entity_id, but this is something they have to provide to me.

Where do I set my entity id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is `settings.issuer`. If you dig into the code used to generate the metadata you will see:

```
 if settings.issuer != nil
    root.attributes["entityID"] = settings.issuer
 end
```

A good way to test your implementation by yourself is using the IDp app that OneLogin provides.

Answer (score 0):

In SAML, each provider has entityID, which is an URL based provider address. Check your provider metadata for entityID.

Comment: I don't see my(SP) entityID specified anywhere in my configs. How do I set it or retrieve it from saml settings object?

Comment: Do you have metadata endpoint for sp service? It must have there.